# Reinitialize the current month name, when i click button

Tags: jsf, calendar, initialization, richfaces

In my **richCalendar.jsp** page, first time i click the **showCurrentMonth** button and display the current month using rich:calendar.
i select some other month
i click **SelectedMonth** button. I show the selected month name.

**My problem is :**
I go to any other page. then i come visit the richCalendar.jsp and again click **showCurrentMonth** button, this time the rich:calendar show the already selected month  instead of current month .
Each time, i want to show current month when i click **showCurrentMonth**.

Otherwise simple, once i click **showCurrentMonth** button, then i selecte some other month,
then i click **showCurrentMonth** button, i want to show current month name.

**richCalendar.jsp**

```
<body>
 <h:form id="calendarForm" binding="#{CalenderBean.initForm}">               
    <rich:panel>                                      
        <a4j:outputPanel id="calendarOutputPanel">              
             <h:panelGrid>                                                      
                 <a4j:commandButton value="showCurrentMonth" 
                                    action="#{CalenderBean.showCurrentMonthAction}"
                                    reRender="monthlyPanelGridId,monthlyCalendarId,calendarOutputPanel"/>                                                          

               <h:panelGrid id="monthlyPanelGridId" rendered="#{CalenderBean.monthlyCalendarRendered}" >
                   <rich:calendar boundaryDatesMode="scroll"
                                  id="monthlyCalendarId" 
                                  showWeekDaysBar="false"
                                               oncurrentdateselected="event.rich.component.selectDate(event.rich.date)"
                                  showFooter="false"
                                  popup="false"
                                  value="#{CalenderBean.selectedMonth}"/>

               </h:panelGrid>

               <h:panelGrid id = "SearchButtonGrid">
                  <a4j:commandButton id="SelectedMonth" 
                      value="SelectedMonth"
                      action="#{CalenderBean.selectedMonthButtonAction}"
                      reRender="calendarOutputPanel"/>

                     <h:outputText value="#{CalenderBean.selectedMonthName}" />

               </h:panelGrid>
          </h:panelGrid>                                                               
   </a4j:outputPanel>
 <rich:panel></h:form></body>
```

**CalenderBean.java**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;        
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;
```

public class CalenderBean
{

```
private HtmlForm initForm;    
private boolean monthlyCalendarRendered;
private Date selectedMonth;
private String selectedMonthName;

public CalenderBean()
{
}

public String showCurrentMonthAction()
{
    monthlyCalendarRendered = true;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startingDate = calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, startingDate);
    selectedMonth = calendar.getTime();       

    return "";
}

public String selectedMonthButtonAction()
{        
    selectedMonthName = selectedMonth.toString();
    return "";
}

public HtmlForm getInitForm()
{       
    selectedMonth = null;
    monthlyCalendarRendered = false;  

    return initForm;
}


public void setInitForm(HtmlForm initForm){
    this.initForm = initForm;
}

public boolean isMonthlyCalendarRendered(){
    return monthlyCalendarRendered;
}

public void setMonthlyCalendarRendered(boolean monthlyCalendarRendered){
    this.monthlyCalendarRendered = monthlyCalendarRendered;
}

public Date getSelectedMonth(){
    return selectedMonth;
}

public void setSelectedMonth(Date selectedMonth){
    this.selectedMonth = selectedMonth;
}

public String getSelectedMonthName(){
    return selectedMonthName;
}

public void setSelectedMonthName(String selectedMonthName){
    this.selectedMonthName = selectedMonthName;
}
}
```

First time i visit this page perfectly show the current month. Then i go to any othe page and then come to see this page, click **showCurrentMonth** button not show the current month.

Help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `popup = "false"` from your calendar control. It will work as you want.

Don't know the reason for this weird behavior but I guess there is some rendering issue.